# How to create df1 from df2 with different row and column indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to fill df1 using df2 values, I could achieve it using nested loop but is very much time taking.
Is there any smart way to do this ?
P.S. The size of df is around 8000 rows , 8000 columns.

df1 initially is like this

```
   A    B    C   D
A  0    0    0   0
B  0    0    0   0
C  0    0    0   0
D  0    0    0   0
```

df2 is like this

```
   P    Q    R   S   T
P  1    5    7   5   3
Q  5    6    2   8   5
R  3    5    4   9   3
S  9    4    5   0   8
T  2    9    4   2   1
```

Now there is correspondence list between indices of df1 and df2

```
df1    df2
A      P
B      Q
C      R
D      S
B      T
```

df1 should be filled like this

```
   A    B    C   D
A  1    8    7   5
B  7    21   6   10
C  3    8    4   9
D  9    12   5   0
```

Here as 'B' is occurring twice in the list, so it will add values of 'Q' and 'T' together.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to include what data type df2 is in the question. Is it a hashtable, a dictionary, a 2-dimensional array. I can already see setting up a dictionary for mapping the letters of df1 to df2 would be good. But without knowing the data structures for these, it's hard to tell what the answer should be.

Comment: It is a 2D array

Comment: You need to also to add why you add that `B` to the correspondence list between indices of df1 and df2. Based on what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try changing the row and col names in df1 (based on the correspondence with df2) and for the cases of multiple correspondence (like B) you could first name them B1, B2, etc... and then sum them together:

```
> di
{'Q': 'B1', 'P': 'A', 'S': 'D', 'R': 'C', 'T': 'B2'}
> df1 = df2.copy()
> df1.columns = [di[c] for c in df2.columns]
> df1.index   = [di[c] for c in df2.index]
> ## sum B1,B2 column wise
> df1['B'] = df1.B1 + df1.B2
> ## sum B1,B2 row wise
> df1.at["B", :] =  df1.loc["B1"] + df1.loc["B2"]
> ## subset with original index and column names
> df1[["A", "B", "C", "D"]].loc[["A", "B", "C", "D"]]
##output
     A     B    C     D
A  1.0   8.0  7.0   5.0
B  7.0  21.0  6.0  10.0
C  3.0   8.0  4.0   9.0
D  9.0  12.0  5.0   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can also stack df2 to a series, as the columns become an inner index(level_1) of a Series.
2. Then replace the indices with `{'P': 'A', 'Q': 'B', 'R': 'C', 'S': 'D', 'T': 'B'}`.
3. use `groupby` with sum to add values with the same indices, then unstack to turn the inner level index to column.

```
amap = {'P': 'A', 'Q': 'B', 'R': 'C', 'S': 'D', 'T': 'B'}
obj2 = df2.stack().reset_index()
for col in ['level_0','level_1']:
    obj2[col] = obj2[col].map(amap)
df1 = obj2.groupby(['level_0', 'level_1'])[0].sum().unstack()
```